# function inside setInterval does not work properly in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have seen many tutorials on creating timers in React by doing something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
     let interval = null;
       if (timeractive) {
         interval = setInterval(() => {
           setCount(count => count+ 1);
         }, 50);
       } else {
         clearInterval(interval);
       }
       return () => clearInterval(interval);
     },[timeractive,count]);
```

This is what I think is happening:

1 `timeractive = true`

2 `useEffect` gets called, declaring assigning the variable `interval` to a `setInterval`

3 `setCount` gets called, incrementing `count`.

4 `useEffect` gets called again since `count` is one of its dependencies. But the cleanup function from the previous `useEffect` runs first, clearing the variable `interval`

5 go back to step 2

I don't want to do things this way because it seems quite unintuitive. It is essentially creating a large "interval" by creating and clearing a bunch of smaller intervals that only lasts one iteration.

So I wrote the following code, trying to create a timer that does not depend on what's being incremented. That why I decided to use useRef so that the interval will be persist between renders.

This is a timer that increases the radius every 100ms and draw a circle with that radius (modulo 50), it is supposed to be an animation but it doesn't work. However the radius seems to be updating fine. So there is something going on with the `drawcircle` function

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575205/setstate-does-not-update-inside-intervalref/59575238#59575238), that's why I decided to pass down an updater function in `setRadius`

Can someone explain the concept of closure in this case?

```js
const {useState,useEffect,useRef} = React;

function Timer({active}) {
    const intervalRef = useRef(null);
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);
    const [width,height] = [500,500];
    const [radius, setRadius] = useState(30);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(active){
            intervalRef.current = setInterval(()=>{
                drawcircle();
                setRadius(radius => radius + 1);
            },100)
        } else {
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current) 
        }
    },[active])
    const drawcircle = ()=>{
      const context = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0,0,width,height)
      context.beginPath()
      context.arc(width/2,height/2,radius%50,0,2*Math.PI)
      context.stroke();
    }
    return (
    <div>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={width} height={height}/>
    <p>radius is {radius}</p>
    </div>
    )
}

function Main() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div>
            <Timer active={active}/>
            <button onClick={()=>{setActive(!active)}}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval callback use the `drawcircle` method of the first render on each iteration and that `drawcircle` method refers to the initial radius value. To solve this, use a ref to `drawcircle` method

```
drawcircleRef = useRef()
useEffect(()=>{
        if(active){
            drawcircleRef.current = drawcircle
            const interval= setInterval(()=>{
                drawcircleRef.current();
                setRadius(radius => radius + 1);
            },100)
           return ()=>  clearInterval(interval) 
        }
    },[active])
useEffect(()=>{
        drawcircleRef.current = drawcircle
    },[radius])
```